# Delete rows that are canceling each other out based on column value in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Current State in df:

```
Index   PN      PI  PostingDate Batch   LDC     AB      MT  Qty Price
11015   4105409 1   12/30/2022  57424   50322   None    22  1   0.05
11016   4105409 1   12/30/2022  57424   50322   None    11  1   0.05
11017   4105157 1   12/29/2022  11619   19436   None    11  4   0.4
11018   None    N   12/29/2022  18424   None    None    11  1   NaN
11019   4104995 5   12/29/2022  14834   None    None    11  2   0.5
11020   4104758 1   12/29/2022  16899   2020    None    11  3   51.07
11021   None    N   12/29/2022  17602   2130    None    11  1   NaN
11022   4104360 16  12/29/2022  16682   2013    None    11  2   44.82
11023   None    N   12/29/2022  18806   None    None    11  1   NaN
11024   4104941 1   12/29/2022  19038   None    None    11  5   15.61
11025   4104459 1   12/28/2022  17652   2020    None    11  2   15.99
11026   4104380 2   12/28/2022  92993   2037    None    11  1   10900
11027   4104901 1   12/28/2022  96084   None    None    11  70  0.07
11028   4105415 1   12/28/2022  69987   None    None    11  1   324.55
11029   4104430 2   12/28/2022  69293   2028    None    11  4   14.34
11030   4104547 6   12/28/2022  17469   None    None    11  2   0.61
11031   None    N   12/28/2022  89600   1822    None    11  1   NaN
11032   4104019 2   12/28/2022  77134   None    None    11  2   1.25
11033   4104430 3   12/28/2022  46079   2028    None    11  2   18.82
11034   4105002 5   12/28/2022  13798   None    None    11  1   8.9
11035   4104187 2   12/28/2022  31287   None    2039    11  4   417.02
11036   4104434 4   12/28/2022  84718   None    None    11  35  0.08
11037   None    N   12/28/2022  24255   None    None    11  1   NaN
11038   4104893 1   12/28/2022  92590   None    None    11  2   0.02
11039   4104327 1   12/28/2022  67448   NONE    None    11  1   1.23
```

Should be:

df should show everything except first 2 rows after calculations because these transactions canceling each other.
I would like to see fields 'Price', 'Batch', 'Qty' and more importantly 'MT' based condition (sometimes MT can be unique while number and amount have duplicates)
Please see if there's an easy solution, thank you!

```
cols = ["Batch", "LDC", "Qty"]
out = (df.assign(n=df.groupby(cols+["Price"]).cumcount(), abs=df["Price"].abs())
   .drop_duplicates(subset=cols+['n'], keep=False)
   .drop(columns=['abs', 'n']))

PS: here: n is assigning 1.0 to additional duplicates, but original transaction is assigned 0.0, so it's not being deleted based on 'n' value?
```

Above script is not working for the mentioned df.

Answer (score 0):

You can group by `Number`, do a sum of `Amount` and filter the dataframe (removing the entries where amount != `0`):

```py
m = df['Amount'].notna()
x = df[m].groupby('Number')['Amount'].transform('sum')

out = pd.concat([df[m & x.ne(0)], df[~m]])
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
  Number ItemNumber Material Loc PostingDate  MType  Qty  Amount
1   4103      00001       D3  DE  2023-06-26     11  1.0   44.65
3   None       None       94  ST  2023-06-25     21  1.0     NaN
```

Comment: Is it possible to include MTypes 11 vs. 21 to make sure they can cancel each other? Because MType is an important control key for me, and I have other MTypes that need same calc

Comment: @bay Can you please [edit] your question and add more `MType`? What if there's other `MType` with the same number and amount `971.40`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can have more than two matching values I would use a [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html), then [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) based on the absolute value:

```
# list of columns that should be identical
# to consider a duplicate
cols = ['Number', 'Item', 'Mat', 'Loc', 'Qty']

out = (df
   .assign(n=df.groupby(cols+['Amount']).cumcount(),
           abs=df['Amount'].abs()
          )
   .drop_duplicates(subset=cols+['n'], keep=False)
   .drop(columns=['abs', 'n'])
 )
```

Output:

```
  Number   Item Mat Loc        Date  MType  Qty  Amount
1   4103  00001  D3  DE  2023-06-26     11  1.0   44.65
3   None   None  94  ST  2023-06-25     21  1.0     NaN
```

Comment: Transaction 2 is deleted from df, but 0 transaction is still showing after applying this calc.  Am I applying it wrong or calc not fitting my original df?

Comment: Do you use `keep=False` in `drop_duplicates`?

Comment: Yes, I pasted your code as is, and it is working but just not deleting initial occurrence.

Comment: @bay can you provide a reproducible format of your input? edit your question and add the output of `df.to_dict('tight')`.

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to share more/actual data since its proprietary in nature. I am dealing with 18 columns and 40k rows. And your code reduced it to 31k so I think its working, but when I did some spot checks, some initial transactions are still there. Future state is that initial transaction eliminated from df. So, the output is dataset showing 0, 2 and 3.  What info are you looking for from df.to_dict?

Comment: I'm sorry but without a reproducible example, what you want is unclear. You **must** provide a clear enough example with a non-trivial input **and the matching expected output** (not a description of it). Without it I cannot help you further.

Comment: I want the same output you posted, rows 0 and 2 removed from my dataset. But for some reason I am unable to get the same result. My input and your output is what I am expecting, but unfortunately something is affecting the actual df.

Comment: Well, then come up with a dummy example that demonstrate your issue. "*when I did some spot checks, some initial transactions are still there*" -> try to craft a minimal example from that

Comment: Update df, but I do not know how to format it like a table in here, sorry. Please see if you can eliminate duplicates in updated df. Thank you.

Comment: Please keep your column names consistent and also provide the exact expected output